# added glasspane makes calls to getMousePosition() for any component return null

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, glasspane

I have written a custom glasspane component and set that to my `JFrame` and `JDialog` classes.
I don't intercept mouse events in the custom glasspane, as I don't need to and also because there are a number of components on the GUI e.g. trees, popups etc which makes it complicated trying to intercept and forward mouse events.
Everything works fine as is - except that whenever I call `getMousePosition()` on any of the other components (e.g. `JPanel`) in the frame/dialog it returns `null`.

On my `JFrame` and `JDialog` classes, I have set the glasspane to `disabled` (but `visible`) and it works for the most part. What do I need to do so the `getMousePosition()` method returns the correct value without having to add mouse event listeners to the glasspane component.

Sample code that demonstrates the problem.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GlassPaneExample
{
private JPanel panel;
private JButton btn;
private JLabel response;
private int counter = 0;

GlassPaneExample()
{
    buildUI();
}

private void buildUI()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GlassPane Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(getPanel());
    frame.setGlassPane(new MyGlassPane());
    frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
    frame.getGlassPane().setEnabled(false);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 220));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

JPanel getPanel()
{
    panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("mousePosition : " + panel.getMousePosition());
            System.out.println("mousePosition(true) : " + panel.getMousePosition(true));
        }
    });

    btn = new JButton("Click here...");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            response.setText("Button click number " + getButtonClickCount());
        }
    });

    response = new JLabel();
    response.setToolTipText("Response label");

    panel.add(btn, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(response, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return panel;
}

private int getButtonClickCount()
{
    return counter++;
}

public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    new GlassPaneExample();
}

class MyGlassPane extends JComponent
{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(10,40,120,120);
    }
}
}
```

If you comment out the 3 lines to do with adding the glasspane to the Frame, then the mouse position point is printed out correctly.
This is a simple example to illustrate the problem, and I've said above, I dont want to add mouse listeners to the custom glasspane component as it introduces other complications.

Comment: I guess you should give a little of your code in order to see where the problem is (unless there are general solutions).

Comment: @EdvinTenovim *"a little of your code"* No, not a little, not a lot, and not even (necessarily) the OP's code. What would be best is for them to post a [mcve]. Oh, and an SO 'power user' tip, you get that complete name and link from putting the characters `[mcve]` in a comment (without the code formatting). OP - voting to close for lack of an MCVE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm just not into Java/Swing, therefore, I don't know a lot of things. If it was PHP/HTML, then I at least would know if it's insufficient information. :)

Comment: @EdvinTenovim *"If it was PHP/HTML, then I at least would know if it's insufficient information."* That's part of what preparing an MCVE is aimed to correct. If it shows the problem and is short, it is an MCVE that's guaranteed to include the problem code. In fact, HTML/CSS/JS (and PHP?) can be embedded ***as*** a runnable example on SO. A pity perhaps that it is not viable to offer that facility for other languages..

Comment: @QuasiG GlassPane consumes mouse event, but doesn't protect against key event, you can to dispatch or redirect mouse events by using methods from SwingUtilities, a few times here about,

Comment: @QuasiG `frame.setGlassPane(new MyGlassPane());`  != `frame.getRootPane.setGlassPane`

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks for pointing out `SwingUtilities`. Unfortunately all the methods in there (relevant to this problem) require either a `Point` or x/y coord values which I don't readily have access to. Also on the point about `frame.setGlassPane != frame.getRootPane.setGlassPane`, this is the setGlassPane method in `JFrame` `public void setGlassPane(Component glassPane) {
        getRootPane().setGlassPane(glassPane);
    }`

Comment: ...looks to me like its the same thing. Or am I missing something?